# Menu and site icons are different for SciFi StackExchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I believe it's not how it should be.

Am I wrong?

[image: Screenshot that demonstrates icons mismatch]

Comment: Looks like [security.se] SE has taken over your computer! Still just the normal SFF icons showing up for me.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ah, thank you, must be local issue then. I'll go deal with invaders.

Comment: This is the gift that keeps on giving... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283807/site-icons-jumbled-up/ - can you try clearing the cache?

Comment: @MarcGravell Whew, it's not just me. I've reloaded The Big Sprite and icons are fine now.

Comment: Going by your last comment above and the fact that nobody else has reported this issue for over a month now, I'm going to mark this as [meta-tag:status-completed].